# Why it succeeds even if the value of ACCESS_MASK is 0 when calling ZwOpenKey

Tags: windows, kernel-module, ntdll

The driver I made does the job of verifying the Registry value in Kernel Mode.

The code is below

```
InitializeObjectAttributes(&ObjAttr,&RegKeyName,OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE | OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE | OBJ_OPENIF,NULL, NULL);

ACCESS_MASK access_mask = 0;
Status = ZwOpenKey(&handle, access_mask, &ObjAttr);
if (!NT_SUCCESS(Status))
    break;

Status = ZwQueryValueKey(handle, ...);
if (!NT_SUCCESS(Status))
    break;
    
Status = ZwDeleteValueKey(handle, &RegKeyName);
if (!NT_SUCCESS(Status))
    break;
    
// So far, I've also succeeded in reading and deleting the values
```

I'm using Windows 10 x64 and I get the same result on 7

I don't know why it works like this

Looking at the ZwQueryValueKey document, it says that KEY_QUERY_VALUE is necessary, but now it succeeds even if it is set to 0.

If anyone knows the reason, can you tell me please